# Enviar email desde laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, angularjs-2.0

config/mail.php

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),


    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION'),


    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=j*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=j*******1805@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=*************
```

controlador

```
Mail::send('emails.confirma',$rq,function($message) use($rq){
                $message->subject('Confirmacion de Registro');
                $message->to($rq['email']);
            });
```

me arroja este error malvado::

```
 (1/1) Swift_TransportException

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

Comment: Ejecuta el **php artisan config:cache** en tu consola para que recargue la configuración y dime si sigue igual.

Comment: [Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException]                        
  Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y43sm24455uag.23 - gsmtp

Comment: " Username and Password not accepted." verifica que estés escribiendo correctamente el usuario y la contraseña